# Add header on top of text area via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this sample code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // sticky profile notes
  const notes = document.querySelector('#id_notes'); // Get textarea element
  const headerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <div> element
  headerDiv.innerHTML = "SHOULD BE ON TOP"; // Insert instructions
  // add header on top 
  notes.prepend(headerDiv);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="id_notes" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
    </textarea>
</body>
```

in which I plan to add a header the same size as the textarea. but instead of it being added on top of the textarea, its being added inside it.

[image]
I can only use JS because I don't know how to add it on a Django template. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: added desired end result:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can put divs inside a textarea as it is a replaced element.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I added a desired end result. I wasn't planning on adding a div inside a text area in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Node#insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // sticky profile notes
  const notes = document.querySelector('#id_notes'); // Get textarea element
  const headerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <div> element
  headerDiv.innerHTML = "SHOULD BE ON TOP"; // Insert instructions
  // add header on top 
  notes.parentNode.insertBefore(headerDiv, notes);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="id_notes" style="background-color: #ffffcc;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) instead

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 
  const notes = document.querySelector('#id_notes'); // Get textarea element
  
  const headerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <div> element
  headerDiv.innerHTML = "SHOULD BE ON TOP"; // Insert instructions
  
  // add header on top 
  notes.parentNode.insertBefore(headerDiv, notes)
});
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="id_notes" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
    </textarea>
</body>
```